# Grails JMS/ActiveMQ stop working whenenver code is changed/recompiled

Tags: grails, jms, activemq-classic

This is very strange. I'm using JMS with ActiveMQ. In development mode, everything works fine but whenever I edit any code in my controller or service methods the queue just stop working.

From the log I can see the messages were sent to the queue but never got received/processed by consumer. I have to stop the run-app and rerun grails run-app. The messages that were sent to the queue got processed upon restart. I couldn't figure out what caused this. Can anybody shed some light? Thanks a lot.

I'm using Grails 2.2.1 with JMS 1.2 plugin and ActiveMQ 5.7.0

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself. So there are two issues combined together and caused this weird behavior.

1. Cached classes
   I have to run grails clean, then grails compile gave me an error about the JMS bean cannot be initiated
2. The error
   It was caused by using a reserved word for method name I guess.

> 

```
@Queue(name="quickBook")
def reserve(msg) {}
```

I changed "reserve" to something else and it works again.

EDIT:
Alright, I was wrong about the second one. For some reason the annotation @Queue caused the problem. So I had to use the service method onMessage() instead.

Edit (06-07-2013):
Was wrong again, it only worked briefly.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm also having this issue. I don't have any compile errors though, cleaning didn't help. The app build just fine, yet every time I save, my method stops getting called. The number of consumers in the ActiveMQ web console is also 0 after I save, so it seems the whole connection is dropped.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Looks like I am not alone here. This problem was not solved for me. If I save the method, the queue stopped working. I've gave up for now. Hopefully someone will figure this out.